# $result & $search in same PHP file

Tags: php, html, search

I want to search with PHP in mysql Database, and search results to edit or delete, but until now i can do search and everything works or Edit/Delete and search dosen't work anymore..

I want to combine both in same php file, but dosen't work. Know someone how to combine ?

How can i add both in same php.. ?

Search PHP

```html
<?php
include_once("db_W3.php");
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM centralhub_lagerbestand");

//load database connection
include_once("db_W3.php");
    $host = "$servername";
    $user = "$username";
    $password = "$password";
    $database_name = "$db";
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database_name", $user, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
 
 
// Search from MySQL database table
$search=$_POST['search'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("select * from centralhub_lagerbestand where KundenNr LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 0 , 50");
 
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
// Display search result


         if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
     
    echo "<table style=\"font-family:arial;color:#333333;\">"; 
                echo "<tr>
    
    <td align='center' style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#A4A4A4;background:#FFFFFF;\">Kunden Nr.:</td>
    <td align='center' style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#A4A4A4;background:#FFFFFF;\">Regal:</td>
    <td align='center' style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#A4A4A4;background:#FFFFFF;\">Regal Ebene:</td> 
                <td align='center' style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#A4A4A4;background:#FFFFFF;\"> Edit </td>     
    </tr>"; 
    
     while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr> <td width='500px' align='center' style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#A4A4A4;\">";   
                echo $results['KundenNr'];
    
    echo "</td><td width='230px' align='center' style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#A4A4A4;\">";
                echo $results['Regal'];
    
    echo "</td><td width='230px' align='center' style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#A4A4A4;\">";
                echo "".$results['RegalEbene'];
    

    

    echo "</td>  </tr>"; 
    
    
    
            }
    echo "</table>";  
        } else {
            echo 'Für die aktuellen Filter wurden keine Ergebnisse gefunden';
        }
?>
```

Edit/Delete PHP

```html
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("db_W3.php");
 
//fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC"); // mysql_query is deprecated
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM centralhub_lagerbestand ORDER BY id DESC"); // using mysqli_query instead
?>
 
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
 
<body> 
    <table width='100%' border=0>
        <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
            <td>KundenNr</td>
            <td>Regal</td>
            <td>RegalEbene</td>
            <td>Update</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, we need to use mysqli_fetch_array 
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$res['KundenNr']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$res['Regal']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$res['RegalEbene']."</td>";    
                   
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want this without page refreshing you have to use ajax.

Comment: Hi Muraru,
It seems that you have not yet implemented any edit/delete code at all, rather have attached maybe your index.php file. Please double check this.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You may pass a parameter name it `act` to the same page and decide what to do according to the`act` required

Comment: can you give me an example?